# rsync is deleting file containing special characters when file name was change in terminal instead of Finder

Tags: macos, command-line, rsync

### The problem

I use macOS and try to sync two directories using rsync – one in my home directory and one in the external HDD (HFS+).

Whenever I run the rsync with `--delete` option, I've observed that it deletes and resends some files, despite no change since the last sync. It concerns only files with special characters (polish characters), which **I renamed using terminal** (mv/cp).

However, the file is tracked correctly if I set the same file name but using a GUI file manager (Finder in macOS).

### Example

I've created a sample file using the command `echo "Hello World" > "witaj świecie.txt"` in  `~/Test/` directory.

I run the rsync using the following command:

```
rsync -avPh --delete  ~/Test/ /Volumes/Vault/Test
```

output:

```
sending incremental file list
created directory /Volumes/Vault/Test
./
witaj świecie.txt
             12 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)

sent 150 bytes  received 80 bytes  460.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.05
```

then, I rerun the same command and the output is:

```
sending incremental file list
deleting witaj świecie.txt
witaj świecie.txt
             12 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)

sent 147 bytes  received 58 bytes  410.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.06
```

Each consecutive execution gives the same output.

When I change the filename using Finder (literally by rewriting the special character), and I run the `rsync` once again, then the output is:

```
sending incremental file list
./

sent 99 bytes  received 19 bytes  236.00 bytes/sec
total size is 12  speedup is 0.10
```

What is responsible for this behavior, and how to fix it?

My environment:

- macOS 12.1
- rsync 3.2.3

```
locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: In Unicode, the "ś" character can be encoded either "composed" as a single character, or "decomposed" as a plain "s" followed by a combining accent; you may be having trouble because it's encoded differently by the different filesystems and/or by Finder vs Terminal. Try `cd`ing to the source and target directories, and do `ls witaj* | LC_ALL=C od -c` to see how they're encoded. Composed "ś" will be octal "305 233", and decomposed will be "s 314 201".

Comment: I've expected that it's related to encoding. Unfortunately, both terminal and Finder use the "composed" variant of the character. I created two files – one from the terminal and one from Finder and the output of the command you suggested contains `305 233` in both files in both source and target directories. However, rsync still works properly only for the file renamed using Finder.

Comment: In that case, I'm stumped as to why the Terminal- vs Finder-created files would be different. Try running `ls -leO@` on them to see if they have any relevant metadata (flags, xattrs, or ACL) differences.

Comment: Actually, I'm even confuseder after thinking for a minute. The HFS+ volume should *always* store "ś" in decomposed format. Did you use `ls witaj*` to get the name (in which case it'll be fetched from the filesystem), or did you fill it in fully on the command line (in which case it'll use what you entered)?

Comment: I've checked the volume once again using diskutil. It's Apple_HFS but with encryption. Yes, I'm using the wildcard `ls *.txt | LC_ALL=C od -c`. There is no difference between these files when it comes to the metadata (`ls -leO@`). I've observed that when I change the part of the name using Finder, the file starts behaving properly even if I didn't replace the special character.